# bootstrap date picker - changing via javascript not syncing with Calender

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a element I'm using as a datepicker:

I set it up using the following script:

```
     $('#fltProdFromQuo').datepicker({
        format: "dd M yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",            
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
     });
```

And set the value to 1st June 2020:

$('#fltProdFromQuo').val('2020-06-01') ;

WHich seems to work until I click the field, and the calander shows todays date:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I've missed to make the calendar show the correct date?

Thank you in advance of any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.   I didn't know that once I set the date I had to "Update" it to change the calender, never had to do this before:

$('#fltProdFromQuo').val('2020-06-01') ;
$('#fltProdFromQuo').datepicker('update');

Working tickety boo now!